# GWT Project compile not working - No errors ,perfectly running on SUPERDEV mode

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt

We have a GWT project using eclipse IDE and we run the project on superdev mode. Till yesterday everything was working fine,but from no where our project stopped compiling there are no errors occurring in the project. There are some warning showed in the console while compilation of the project.

Now, **Problem is project is perfectly running on super dev mode every functionality added is working fine no errors no problems.**

Its like if we have some error we can just sort them but with no error unable to find the problem. Tried to study & search but couldn't find anything helpful that landed me on SO.

**USING:-**

GWT-2.8.0

GWT Material

eclipse luna

```
 Compiling module com.edubot.Edubot
   Computing all possible rebind results for 'com.edubot.client.enggheads.web.homepage.HomePageBase.HomePageBaseUiBinder'
      Rebinding com.edubot.client.enggheads.web.homepage.HomePageBase.HomePageBaseUiBinder
         Invoking generator com.google.gwt.uibinder.rebind.UiBinderGenerator
            The following problems were detected
               [WARN] Line 29 column 25: encountered ":". Was expecting one of: "}" "+" "-" "," ";" "/" <STRING> <IDENT> <NUMBER> <URL> <PERCENTAGE> <PT> <MM> <CM> <PC> <IN> <PX> <EMS> <EXS> <DEG> <RAD> <GRAD> <MS> <SECOND> <HZ> <KHZ> <DIMEN> <HASH> <IMPORTANT_SYM> <UNICODERANGE> <FUNCTION> 
   Computing all possible rebind results for 'com.edubot.client.enggheads.web.homepage.HomePageBase_HomePageBaseUiBinderImpl_GenBundle'
      Rebinding com.edubot.client.enggheads.web.homepage.HomePageBase_HomePageBaseUiBinderImpl_GenBundle
         Invoking generator com.google.gwt.resources.rebind.context.InlineClientBundleGenerator
            Preparing method style
               The following problems were detected
                  [WARN] Line 29 column 25: encountered ":". Was expecting one of: "}" "+" "-" "," ";" "/" <STRING> <IDENT> <NUMBER> <URL> <PERCENTAGE> <PT> <MM> <CM> <PC> <IN> <PX> <EMS> <EXS> <DEG> <RAD> <GRAD> <MS> <SECOND> <HZ> <KHZ> <DIMEN> <HASH> <IMPORTANT_SYM> <UNICODERANGE> <FUNCTION> 
      Rebinding com.edubot.client.enggheads.web.homepage.HomePageBase_HomePageBaseUiBinderImpl_GenBundle
         Invoking generator com.google.gwt.resources.rebind.context.InlineClientBundleGenerator
            Preparing method style
               The following problems were detected
                  [WARN] Line 29 column 25: encountered ":". Was expecting one of: "}" "+" "-" "," ";" "/" <STRING> <IDENT> <NUMBER> <URL> <PERCENTAGE> <PT> <MM> <CM> <PC> <IN> <PX> <EMS> <EXS> <DEG> <RAD> <GRAD> <MS> <SECOND> <HZ> <KHZ> <DIMEN> <HASH> <IMPORTANT_SYM> <UNICODERANGE> <FUNCTION> 
      Rebinding com.edubot.client.enggheads.web.homepage.HomePageBase_HomePageBaseUiBinderImpl_GenBundle
         Invoking generator com.google.gwt.resources.rebind.context.InlineClientBundleGenerator
            Preparing method style
               The following problems were detected
                  [WARN] Line 29 column 25: encountered ":". Was expecting one of: "}" "+" "-" "," ";" "/" <STRING> <IDENT> <NUMBER> <URL> <PERCENTAGE> <PT> <MM> <CM> <PC> <IN> <PX> <EMS> <EXS> <DEG> <RAD> <GRAD> <MS> <SECOND> <HZ> <KHZ> <DIMEN> <HASH> <IMPORTANT_SYM> <UNICODERANGE> <FUNCTION> 
   Computing all possible rebind results for 'com.edubot.client.post.web.EmptyPost.EmptyClassesUiBinder'
      Rebinding com.edubot.client.post.web.EmptyPost.EmptyClassesUiBinder
         Invoking generator com.google.gwt.uibinder.rebind.UiBinderGenerator
            The following problems were detected
               [WARN] Line 10 column 32: encountered "!". Was expecting one of: "}" "+" "-" "," ";" "/" <STRING> <IDENT> <NUMBER> <URL> <PERCENTAGE> <PT> <MM> <CM> <PC> <IN> <PX> <EMS> <EXS> <DEG> <RAD> <GRAD> <MS> <SECOND> <HZ> <KHZ> <DIMEN> <HASH> <IMPORTANT_SYM> <UNICODERANGE> <FUNCTION> 
   Computing all possible rebind results for 'com.edubot.client.post.web.EmptyPost_EmptyClassesUiBinderImpl_GenBundle'
      Rebinding com.edubot.client.post.web.EmptyPost_EmptyClassesUiBinderImpl_GenBundle
         Invoking generator com.google.gwt.resources.rebind.context.InlineClientBundleGenerator
            Preparing method style
               The following problems were detected
                  [WARN] Line 10 column 32: encountered "!". Was expecting one of: "}" "+" "-" "," ";" "/" <STRING> <IDENT> <NUMBER> <URL> <PERCENTAGE> <PT> <MM> <CM> <PC> <IN> <PX> <EMS> <EXS> <DEG> <RAD> <GRAD> <MS> <SECOND> <HZ> <KHZ> <DIMEN> <HASH> <IMPORTANT_SYM> <UNICODERANGE> <FUNCTION> 
      Rebinding com.edubot.client.post.web.EmptyPost_EmptyClassesUiBinderImpl_GenBundle
         Invoking generator com.google.gwt.resources.rebind.context.InlineClientBundleGenerator
            Preparing method style
               The following problems were detected
                  [WARN] Line 10 column 32: encountered "!". Was expecting one of: "}" "+" "-" "," ";" "/" <STRING> <IDENT> <NUMBER> <URL> <PERCENTAGE> <PT> <MM> <CM> <PC> <IN> <PX> <EMS> <EXS> <DEG> <RAD> <GRAD> <MS> <SECOND> <HZ> <KHZ> <DIMEN> <HASH> <IMPORTANT_SYM> <UNICODERANGE> <FUNCTION> 
      Rebinding com.edubot.client.post.web.EmptyPost_EmptyClassesUiBinderImpl_GenBundle
         Invoking generator com.google.gwt.resources.rebind.context.InlineClientBundleGenerator
            Preparing method style
               The following problems were detected
                  [WARN] Line 10 column 32: encountered "!". Was expecting one of: "}" "+" "-" "," ";" "/" <STRING> <IDENT> <NUMBER> <URL> <PERCENTAGE> <PT> <MM> <CM> <PC> <IN> <PX> <EMS> <EXS> <DEG> <RAD> <GRAD> <MS> <SECOND> <HZ> <KHZ> <DIMEN> <HASH> <IMPORTANT_SYM> <UNICODERANGE> <FUNCTION> 
   Compiling 2 permutations
      Compiling permutation 0...
```

This the point it just stops working and the problem start.

Until the project gets compiled we can't create its war file and unable to host the project globally on tomcat.

Comment: Have you tried to compile the project with logLevel TRACE?

Comment: Showing us the source for the `com.edubot.*` classes mentioned, as well as the `.ui.xml` files would be helpful, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem has been resolved there was a function in my project which was been called infinite times due to some mistake. Finally after reading the classes and debugging the code we found the problem.